# Scala: detect cyrillic and latin characters in string?

Tags: string, scala

Please help with a simple Scala method that allows to:

1. Detect if string contains at least one Latin character
2. Detect if all string characters are Latin
3. Detect if string contains at least one Cyrillic character
4. Detect if all string characters are Cyrillic

So far I tried:

```
scala> val pattern = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]")
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = [a-zA-Z]
scala> val s = "john"
s: String = john
scala> pattern findFirstIn s
res22: Option[String] = Some(j)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you at least show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please, see my question update

Comment: What's your definition of 'latin'? A-Za-z seems restrictive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

**1. One latin char**

```
scala> ("[A-Za-z]".r findFirstIn "Munich").isDefined
res22: Boolean = true
```

**2. All latin char**

```
scala> "Munich".toList.forall(c => ( c >= 'A' && c<= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') )
res27: Boolean = true
```

**3. At least one Cyrillic char:**

```
("\\p{IsCyrillic}".r findFirstIn "Москва").isDefined
res5: Boolean = true
```

**4. Are all chars Cyrillic:**

```
val moscow = "Москва"

"\\p{IsCyrillic}*".r.findFirstIn(moscow).map(_.size) == Some(moscow.size)
res21: Boolean = true
```

Comment: In 4) `findFirstIn` finds just one char and size is always 1.

Comment: no. Try the code, there is a slight difference in 4. there is a Kleene star "*".

Comment: I regret I speak no language that uses Cyrillic, but the Cyrillic seems to tests for Cyrillic characters (any character in the Cyrillic block), while the latin test tests for latin _letters_ (and excludes other non-letter characters in the latin block). Hence the tests are not symmetric?